# Schedule not working in live environment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, syncfusion

I am using Syncfusion Schedule version 10.204.0.56.
When i click on calendar , i am able to go to whole view of calendar.
From there when i double click, i am able to save appointment in **local environment**.
But when i uploaded my code to server , then it is not working on live environment .
I am not able to save appointment in live environment.

I have schedule control and i am trying to save appointment.
But when i click on save button, nothing happens.
Then i debug in browser, and i got error that my **start time** and **endtime** is **'NAN'**.

But this system, working perfect in local environment.

Can anyone please help me...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Uma, Finally its working.
The problem was in schedule script.
I have added below code in my schedulescript

```
  .TimeZone(ScheduleTimeZones.India_Standard_Time)
```

And also i have removed dll references and again added to my application.

And now its working like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve used the Schedule control in my application, but I didn’t face any such problem while saving the appointments in local and hosted environment:

1. The ambiguity/conflict between the date format  might have caused this issue, so check the date format that you use in your local system matches the date format of the Schedule control in live server, because they have used the default format as “MM/dd/YYYY” and “en-US” culture.
2. Also, make sure that all the required dlls including AjaxMin are getting referred correctly, after your application being hosted in the live environment.

If possible, share some more details in order to reproduce this issue, so that it will be easier for me to debug what went wrong with it. Or contact their support, they will help you to resolve issues.